# How to register a webhook url in Twitter?

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

How to register a Twitter Webhook URL in Twitter? I am successful in authorizing my app using application-only authentication. I believe that app-only authentication is required in sending POST Request in https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/webhooks.json.

So Here is my code,

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', {
    params: { 'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+base64token
    }
},function (error, response) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        token = response.data.access_token;

        HTTP.call('POST', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/webhooks.json', {
            params: { 'url':'https://someurl.com/twitter'},
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
            }
        },function (error, response) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.error(error.message);
            }
        }); 
    } else {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
});
```

The error I received is " {"errors":[{"code":261,"message":"Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform."}]}"

What is the problem here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your code looks all good, just tested it, and it runs. So I'd say a problem with your Twitter credentials/ API keys

Comment: You cannot access to actions that implies write operations on your app using Application-Only Authorization. You need Single-User OAuth to perform this tasks, and before this, you need to be approved here: https://gnipinc.formstack.com/forms/account_activity_api_configuration_request_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is caused by supposedly breaching terms of service. It's reasonably common and easy enough to get resolved.

### Determining whether your app has been restricted

- Log into the account that you used to register the application
- Visit Twitter's application management site (https://apps.twitter.com)
- On that page,"Unable to perform write actions" will appear below the
  name of your application only if the app can no longer perform write
  actions;

[image]

### Result of Restrictions

Attempts to access write-based Twitter API methods, such as statuses/update or favorites/create, through an API key in this state will result in our API returning an HTTP 403 response error: “Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.”

### How to resolve

Raise a ticket on the Twitter support page, here: https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform

Appealing only takes 5 minutes, and Twitter is very fast to resolve

Comment: There is no restricted from performing write actions notification in my app.

Comment: Are you sure, because that is what error `261` is caused by?

Comment: I have managed to get your code snippet running with my API keys- your code seems fine

Comment: Yes @lissy. I can't see any restriction notification.

Comment: What did you put in your base64token? is it the client key&secret? or access token& access token secret?

Comment: Yes, should work - can you confirm that you don't get this error in Postman?

Comment: Then it is a problem with your credentials, rather than your code

Comment: What did you use in your Basic token?

Comment: Just `Authorization: 'Basic ' + base64`

Comment: The base64 is combination of client key and secret?

Comment: The access token

Comment: How to create base64 with the access token? I tried this, access_token + ":" + access_token_secret. then convert to base64.. the error is Bad Authentication data.